# how to remove the error tables in the contents

Tags: filter, powerquery

I'm using Current workbook as source but I have error tables in the list. I couldn't remove  these error data from the contents.

```
let
     Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()

in Source
```

[image: errors]

As it does not see it as text, I cannot filter the Content column. How can I remove the errors in the content?

Comment: @horseyride i tried this ofcourse and it didnt remove...

Comment: @horseyride it shows the print areas and also filtered tables as separate error tables on the list

Comment: @horseyride i can share a sample file if you'd like to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting problem.  Filtering Table.RowCount seems to be the way to go.

Try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each (try Table.RowCount([Content])>0 otherwise false))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: this code removed the errors like a charm, thank you... but i still have the print areas as tables in the list 

Comment: i removed them with a filter... ``not Text.Contains([Name], "Print_Area")``